# Find the operator norm of a bounded linear functional

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let a linear functional $L:C[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $L(f)=\int_{-1}^1 t f(t) dt$ for all $f\in C[-1,1]$.

Find the operator norm of L, where the operator norm of L is defined as $\|L\| = sup_{f\neq 0} |L(f)|/\|f\|_\infty $

Here is my attempt:
$$ |L(f)| \leq \int_{-1}^1 |t|\cdot |f(t)| dt \leq |f\|_{\infty}\cdot\int_{-1}^{1}|t|dt = \|f\|_{\infty}   $$
therefore $\|L\|\leq 1 $.

Now I am trying to show that $|L(g)|/\|g\|_\infty= 1$ holds for some $g\in C[-1,1]$ which would imply $\|L\|= 1 $ , however I am struggling to find a continuous function g such that this holds.

Is there a function such that this holds or is the upper bound I have calculated too large?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you know that $\int_{-1}^1 tH(t)dt=1$ where

$H(t)=\begin{cases} 1\quad  \quad \quad 0\le x\le 1 &\\ -1\quad -1\le x<0\end{cases}$

but $H$ is not continuous, so try to find a sequence of continuous functions that converge to $H$ on $[-1,1]$. Since the problem with $H$ is the jump at $x=0,$ back off a little and define

$H_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1\quad  \quad \quad 1/n\le x\le 1 &\\ ?? \quad -1/n\le x\le 1/n&\\-1 \quad -1\le x<-1/n\end{cases}.$

Comment: I have computed $\|LH_n\|$ and the desired result is obtained as $n\to\infty$. However, why am I allowed to take this limit if H is not a continuous linear functional?

Comment: You do not need to take a limit. Just show that for all $ϵ>0$, there is an $H_n$ that makes the absolute value of integral $ϵ$− close to $1.$

Answer (score 1):

Not alwayes you can find such functions, but you can true to constract sequence $g_n(x) \in C[-1, 1]$ such that $\|Lg_n\| \nearrow  1$, if you do this you automatically obtain $\|L\| = 1$